# vertica how restrict database size

Tags: vertica

Could you please help me with the following issue?
I have installed vertica cluster. I can't understand how I can restrict database size in time or in size. For example, data in a database must be deleted older than 30 days or when a database size of 100 GB is reached (what comes first)

Answer (score 0):

There is no automated way of doing this, and no logical way of "restricting database size". You can't just trim "data" from a "database".

What are you talking about (in terms of limiting data outside of 30 days old) needs to be done on the table level. You would need some kind of date field and delete anything older than 30 days. However, I would advice against deleting rows in this way. It is non-performant and can cause queries against the table to be slow: see [DELETE and UPDATE Performance Considerations](https://www.vertica.com/docs/10.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AnalyzingData/Optimizations/PerformanceConsiderationsForDELETEAndUPDATEQueries.htm). The best way of doing this would be to partition the table by day, and create an automated script (bash, python, etc) to each day drop the partition that corresponds with the date 30 days ago: see [Dropping Partitions](https://www.vertica.com/docs/10.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Partitions/DroppingPartitions.htm?zoom_highlight=drop%20partitions).

As for deleting data—if the size of the "database" goes above 100GB—this requirement is extremely vague and would be impossible to enforce. Let's say you have 50 tables, and the size of several of those tables grows so that the total size of the database is over 100GB, how would you decide which table to prune? This also must be done on a table by table level (or in this case—technically—on a projection level, since that is where the data is actually stored).

To see the compressed size (size on disk) of the database you can use this query:

```sql
SELECT SUM(used_bytes) / ( 1024^3 ) AS database_size_gb
FROM projection_storage;
```

However, since data can only be deleted with a `DELETE` or `DROP PARTITION` statement on a table, it would also be helpful to see the size of each table. You can do this by using this query:

```sql
SELECT projection_schema, anchor_table_name, SUM(used_bytes) / ( 1024^3 ) AS table_size_gb
FROM projection_storage
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

From the results you can decide which tables you want to prune.

---

A couple of notes (as a Vertica DBA):

Data is stored in projections. Having too many projections on a single table can not only cause queries to be slow but will also increase the overall data footprint. Avoid using too many projections (especially too many superprojections, don't have more than two per table, and most tables will only need one). Use the database designer or follow the guidelines in the documentation for creating custom projections: [Design Fundamentals](https://www.vertica.com/docs/10.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/ConfiguringTheDB/PhysicalSchema/DesignFundamentals.htm).

Also, another trick to keep database size down is to use the [DESIGNER_DESIGN_PROJECTION_ENCODINGS](https://www.vertica.com/docs/10.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/VerticaFunctions/DatabaseDesigner/DESIGNER_DESIGN_PROJECTION_ENCODINGS.htm) function. Unless your projections are created with the database designer, they will likely only contain the auto encoding. Using the `DESIGNER_DESIGN_PROJECTION_ENCODINGS` function will help you to pick the most optimal encoding for each column. I have seen properly encoded projections take up a mere 2% disk size compared to the previously un-optimized projection. That is rare, but in my experience you will still see at least a 20-40% reduction in size. Do not be afraid to use this function liberally. It is one of my favorite tools as a Vertica DBA.
Also